# How to display custom properties in design view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

How can I make my custom properties appear in the edmx design view of the latest version of Entity framework?

I added a custom property to a partial class like so:

```
public partial class Survey
{
public IEnumerable<Data.Users> answers
  {
   get;
   set;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. Entities are generated from `edmx` file by EntityModelCodeGenerator (T4 generation), not vice versa. Any changes in entities either original generated classes, or partial created by you, will not affect `edmx` file.

So, if you want to see property in `edmx` design view, then modify `edmx` file instead. Select your `Survey` entity at `edmx` diagram, and from context menu pick `Add New...`. You can add Scalar, Navigation, or Complex property here. Property will appear on you generated entity.